# Handle the deletion of detail in one to many master-detail relationship - hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a very typical scenario of one to many relationship (one request record and with request details records) that are retreived through hibernate, detached from session, modified then saved again after modification with hibernate also, ... Now suppose one of the details record is deleted at the client side and I want to persist that it's deleted (delete it from the data base) ... The current logic does the following (on each update ): retreive all slave records again, compare the client input with the persisted records, if any record is missing this means that is deleted, so a `session.delete` call is fired to delete the nominated record ... Then finally the entity is updated `session.update` .... I wonder if there's another way to let provider notice that the record was deleted without doing this comparison ... Any help?

Answer (score -1):

you can use cascade and delete orphan option to make your parent changes impact child like :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Then you need to use Session.update() or Session.merge() for reattachment of detached instances. this way any changes you make will be saved at the end of your transaction(on commit).

This is my code example:

```
    session.persist(a1);
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();//a1 saved

    session.evict(a1);//a1 detached

    a1.getTableBs().remove(0);//remove child

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(a1);//reattach a1
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
```

And at the end of my transaction hibernate run query like this to delete the child:

```
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    TABLE_B 
where
    ID=?
```

Comment: As I know, Orphan removal won't work as long as the orphaned object is detached ... So I will need to read the whole entity again from database ... Remove the nominated detail object then update ... Do it's the same scenario

Comment: no it work, when you re-attach(using merge/update) it will remove the child that's been removed on commit. Already try this in my local to make sure this is working.

Comment: I just tried it in my code, and as expected, it only works if the removal is done while the entity is managed, if the removal is done before the entity is managed, it wont be reflected in the database ... only new details are added but removed details are still there in the database

Comment: From "Pro JPA 2" p. 286 : "Finally, if the orphaned object is not currently managed in the persistence context, either because it has been
created in memory and not yet persisted or because it is simply detached from the persistence context, orphan
removal will not be applied. Similarly, if it has already been removed in the current persistence context orphan
removal will not be applied"